# Unknown issue injecting mock service into angular test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

This is my module declaration:

```
(angular.module 'services.date', [])

.service '$date', () ->
  # stuff
  this
```

This is my injection code:

```
describe 'Service: dateService', () ->
  dateService = null
  beforeEach module 'services.date'
  beforeEach inject (_$date_) ->
    dateService = _$date_

  describe 'Test', () ->
    it 'should test stuff', () ->
      (expect true).toBe true
```

If I run this code I get this error:

```
Firefox 37.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Service: dateService Test should test stuff FAILED
    minErr/<@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular/angular.js:68:12
    loadModules/<@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular/angular.js:4411:15
    forEach@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular/angular.js:336:11
    loadModules@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular/angular.js:4372:5
    createInjector@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular/angular.js:4297:11
    workFn@/home/pv/Sites/web/ngbp-coffee/vendor/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2172:44
```

Now here's the interesting part: If I comment out the injection code, the test passes:

```
describe 'Service: dateService', () ->
  # dateService = null
  # beforeEach module 'services.date'
  # beforeEach inject (_$date_) ->
  #   dateService = _$date_

  describe 'Test', () ->
    it 'should test stuff', () ->
      (expect true).toBe true
```

// after running

```
Firefox 37.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.003 secs / 0.002 secs)

Done, without errors.
```

What is it about how I'm injecting the service that's wrong? Please help.

**UPDATE**

It looks like the `$injector` service cannot recognize my other service. If I do

```
$injector.has '$date'
```

I get `false`

WTF am I doing wrong?????

Comment: I have found that ordering the dependencies are really important when running unit-tests. Are you sure you are including your $date before your dateService?

Comment: Yes, all dependencies are being loaded in order.

Comment: Is there an error if you just leave the first beforeEach in?

Comment: is $date your own service? I don't know but it's a pretty common name, have you tried to rename it to something that not could conflict with some other $date-service

Comment: does $date have any dependencies? if so then you might to inject them to before injecting $data.

Comment: Changing the name of the date service did not help either

Comment: Can you paste your karma configuariton file? Along with your folder structure for all your files (tests/app). I have a sneaking suspicion it's not picking up your application.

Comment: Have you included your file with `$date` service to karma config? It has to be listed in `files` option before your test file.

Comment: Piggybacking on @MichaelRadionov's question, try running a `console.log('whatever')` inside your file for dateService. If you get that in your console (I'm assuming you're running the progress checker), you'll know the file is loaded. Otherwise, your Karma configuration is off. It's kind of a dirty test, but it's worked for me in the past and can help rule out that issue.

Comment: Is karma aware of the file the $date service is in?

Answer (score 0):

The ["Underscore Wrapping"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) is only useful when you do not want to hide your variable (dateService) with the injected reference (_ $date _). Meaning that using _ $date _ is only useful if you want to call your variable "$date" (not dateService).

However, it does not solve your issue. $injector should have '$date'. I guess we can't help you without more code. Something is probably wrong with your factory declaration or with the configuration file given to Karma, as, obviously, "$date" has not been loaded.

The same code is working for me (with an empty factory, however).